# running a executable in Windows using mingw32 g++

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I am trying to run the files given [here](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~aaron/research/fastmodularity.htm)

The page says:

```
Running the program

The Makefile provided should be sufficient to compile the executable (built in ANSI C/C++ with platform independent code). This usage information can be retrieved by running the executable with no arguments:

-f <filename>   give the target .pairs file to be processed
-l <text>   the text label for this run; used to build output filenames
-t <int>    timer period for reporting progress of file input to screen
-s  calculate and record the support of the dQ matrix
-v --v ---v differing levels of screen output verbosity
-c <int>    record the aglomerated network at step <int> (typically, this is the step location at which the modularity is known to be maximum)
(Please see the notes in the .cc file for the most up-to-date version of this information.) The typical usage will be to first create the .pairs file containing your network, to run the program like

• ./fastcommunity_mh -f myNetwork.pairs -l firstRun

and then consult the file outputs as described below. If you want to then examine the communities that have been built by the algorithm, you would run the algorithm a second time like so

• ./fastcommunity_mh -f myNetwork.pairs -l secondRun -c X

where X is the integer value for the maximum modularity that is reported in the .info file. Again, this could probably be automated, either by modifying the code, or wrapping it all in another script.
```

---

Now when I type

```
./ FastCommunityMH
```

I get

```
'.' is not not recognized as internal or external command.
```

How can I run the codes here??

Comment: The syntax with "./" in front is for unix style shells. From windows cmd you need to use ".\". You need to run make before trying this, though.

Comment: how do I run make before this?

Comment: I think you might need to install cygwin to get a copy of make, mingw and friends. It will also come with bash and a terminal emulator (mintty).

Comment: I suspect, that all make tutorial is "The Makefile provided should be sufficient to compile the executable (built in ANSI C/C++ with platform independent code)." And then usage of already built program is shown. Try just `make` to build and see what happens.

Comment: Can you give an example for this> Suppose I have to run a file FastCommunityMH..How shall I go about?

Comment: After that, you just run "make" in the directory with the files.

Comment: @ctn, NO! Cygwin is an evil! [Mingw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) is much better.

Comment: by doing so I get FastCommunityMH uptodate

Comment: after that I ran .\FastCommunity. The Command line says that '.\FastCommunity' is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: Any example about my previosu comment

Comment: You have a space between the `/` and `FastCommunityMH`!